# Meshing a thin tube

Tags: graphics, mesh, finite-element-method

I'd like to mesh a thin tube. The following gives a strange result when `thickness` becomes too small:

```
height = 3;
radius = 1;
thickness = .06;

ir = ImplicitRegion[(radius - thickness)^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= radius && 
    0 <= z <= height, {x, y, z}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[
  ir, {{-radius, radius}, {-radius, radius}, {0, height}}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0003]
```

[image]

As you can see it is not quite a cylinder...

Ideally, I'd like to mesh cylinders with `thickness`es as small as `0.005`. How can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can sometimes happen if the region bounds intersect with the region it self. If you look at the output of the `ElementMesh` you will see that it's bounds do not go from `-radius` to `radius`.

```
mesh["Bounds"]
{{-0.995306, 0.995306}, {-0.995306, 0.995306}, {0., 3.}}
```

The fix is easy: just enlarge the bounding box a bit:

```
height = 3;
radius = 1;
thickness = .06;
rt = radius + 0.1;

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ir = ImplicitRegion[(radius - thickness)^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= radius && 
    0 <= z <= height, {x, y, z}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[ir, {{-rt, rt}, {-rt, rt}, {0, height}}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0003];
```

Look at the bounds:

```
mesh["Bounds"]
{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {0., 3.}}
```

Look at the mesh:

```
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

**Update:**

Another option is to manually generate the a hex element based mesh for this case:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

nx = 100; ny = 5; nz = 100;
coordinates = 
  Flatten[ Table[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], h}, {h, 0., 
     3., (3 - 0)/(nz - 1)}, {r, 1. - 0.05, 
     1., (1. - (1 - 0.05))/(ny - 1)}, {\[Theta], 0., 
     2 Pi, (2 Pi - 0.)/(nx - 1)}], 2];

mkIncidents = 
  Compile[{{nx, _Integer, 0}, {ny, _Integer, 0}, {nz, _Integer, 0}},
   Flatten[
    Table[Block[{p1 = (j - 1)*nx + i, p2 = j*nx + i, p3 = p2 + 1, 
       p4 = p1 + 1, p5, p6, p7, p8},
      {p5, p6, p7, p8} = {p1, p2, p3, p4} + k*nx*ny;
      {p1, p2, p3, p4} += (k - 1)*nx*ny;
      {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8}], {i, 1, nx - 1}, {j, 1, 
      ny - 1}, {k, 1, nz - 1}], 2]
   ];

incidents = mkIncidents[nx, ny, nz];

mesh = 
 ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
  "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[incidents]}]

ElementMesh[{{-0.999497, 1.}, {-0.999874, 0.999874}, {0., 
   3.}}, {HexahedronElement["<" 39204 ">"]}]

mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Playing with the `nx`,`ny` and `nz` allows you to influence the the quality which you can inspect with:

```
Histogram[mesh["Quality"]]
```

Comment: Do you manage to mesh with `thickness = 0.01`? I either get an error, or I can reduce `MaxCellMeasure` but it never ends.

Comment: @anderstood, yes with `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0000015` it gives me 1.3M tets. I am a bit surprised that I need to specify the MaxCellMeasure, but I assume because of the high aspect ratio the automatic MaxCellMeasure computation fails. This does not look quite correct.

Comment: OK, thanks. I stopped the computation after 30 min... Anyway I think the mesh is not quite optimal for the FEM (elements are pretty distorted). I need to read more about meshing with Mathematica. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @anderstood with V11.2 on my laptop it took 70sec. so 30 Min is way too long. Another idea: See update.