# Shell elements in FEM

Tags: differential-equations, mesh, finite-element-method

I was wondering how to find the modes of a shell (i.e., a structure with one dimension [the thickness] smaller than the two others).

Consider for instance the following `CapsuleShape`:

```
thickness = 0.2;
capExt = CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}, 1.5];
capInt = CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}, 1.5 - thickness];
reg = RegionDifference[capExt, capInt];
RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotPoints -> 100, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 12}}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5]]]
```

[image]

Now, using the great answer by user21 [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164866/18767), I can compute the modes (I don't add the code because it is virtually the same)---the red corresponds to a Dirichlet condition with the following mesh:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-4, 14}}, 
            MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]
```

[image]

The issue is when I want to see what happens if I reduce the value of `thickness`. I asked a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165003/18767) and user21 proposed to solutions:

- enlarging the bounding box in `ToElementMesh`: this does not change anything for this case;
- meshing by hand: quite tedious for that example.

Of course the most natural approach would be to reduce the max elements size with `MaxCellMeasure`, but the computation becomes too extensive, especially given that the elements mustn't be too elongated.

The nicest approach would probably to use some other types of elements, namely *shell elements*, instead of volume elements. Shell elements are surface elements, they have no thickness, but they do have a bending stiffness. I was wondering if and how shell elements could be implemented in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Bhatti, M. Asghar; [Advanced Topics in Finite Element Analysis of Structures: With Mathematica and MATLAB Computations](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Topics-Element-Analysis-Structures/dp/0471648078/) has a treatment of this in Chapter 6. Though I have not read the chapter, Bhatti's FEM books are very good; so I'd start here. Would be nice to see an implementation here.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for the reference, I managed to borrow the book. For those interested, the Mathematica codes are available [there](http://higheredbcs.wiley.com/legacy/college/bhatti/0471648078/mathematica/mathematica.zip). Most relevant here is probably Implementation 6.7. Hopefully I will come back in a few days with something interesting.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Answer (score 5):

[AceFEM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/acegen/info) package offers numerous element topologies and formulations, including shell elements. (I think you can get free trial version of package for non-commercial use from their [website](http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/Download.htm).)

This is mesh obtained from OP's region.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
capExt = CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}, 1.5];
mesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  capExt, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-4, 14}},"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1, "MeshOrder" -> 1
]

Show[
  mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm[LightBlue]]], 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}
]
```

[image: mesh]

The next function uses `mesh` generated with Mathematica and assembles the stiffness matrix. Element properties are inferred from code given in `SMTAddDomain` function.

```
<< AceFEM`

setup[mesh_ElementMesh, thickness_?Positive] := Module[
  {nodes, elementConnectivity},
  nodes = mesh["Coordinates"];
  elementConnectivity = First@ElementIncidents@mesh["BoundaryElements"];

  SMTInputData[];
  (* Element subroutine is downloaded from online repository.
  Its type is Mindlin shell with linear elastic material assumption. *)
  SMTAddDomain["Capsule","OL:SEMSP1DFLEP1P6Hooke", {"t*" -> thickness}];
  SMTAddMesh[nodes, {"Capsule" -> elementConnectivity}];
  (* Displacements for all nodes at coordinate Z==0 are prescribed to zero.
  The first 3 DOF per node are displacement, the other 3 are rotations. *)
  SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{"Z" == 0 &, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0}];
  SMTAnalysis[]
  ]
```

After the stiffness matrix (and other data structures) are assembled, `SMTShowEigenvectors` shows specified number of eigenmodes and corresponding frequencies. (Since I don't have much experience with this kind of analysis, I can't say if results are correct.)

```
setup[mesh, 0.2]

Row[SMTShowEigenvectors[SMTData["TangentMatrix"], 7, "Scale" -> 1, ImageSize -> 100]]
```

[image: eigenmodes]

[image: animation]

Comment: What PDE does this solve?

Comment: @user21 It's linear elasticity. This is Navier-Cauchy equation, right?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that should be Navier-Cauchy or it's cousins like the stress operator in 3D.